# Using UTC with Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'd like to not store times in my local timezone, but Sequel is making it really tough on me. I can set them to UTC before I put them in there (a bit of a pain), but then when I take them back out it assumes that they are local dates and then they are all 8 hours in the future. Is this something that hasn't been implemented yet? And if so, are there any workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to try to put them in as UTC is to override literal_datetime and/or literal_time for the dataset class you are using to return a literal string of the UTC time.

Getting them out in UTC depends on the adapter you are using.  For example, the postgres adapter calls Sequel.string_to_datetime, which just calls parse on the Sequel.datetime_class (Time by default).  If the datetime column includes the timezone information, things should work fine.  If it doesn't include timezone information, Time.parse is going to assume it is given a local time.  In that case, you may want to override Sequel.string_to_datetime to make sure it always returns the time with the UTC offset (maybe by calling Time.parse(s).gmtime).

Answer (score 25):

This is a bit outdated at this point but I believe the best solution here has changed since the original answer was posted. If you set

```
Sequel.default_timezone = :utc
```

sequel will treat all times as UTC and wont exhibit the behavior described in the question.

Find more info at http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Timezones.html

Answer (score 5):

Just had a very similar issue myself.

This information has been taken from the [Sequel RDoc](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel.html)

> Sequel can use either Time or DateTime
>   for times returned from the database.
>   It defaults to Time. To change it to
>   DateTime, use:

```
Sequel.datetime_class = DateTime
```

Also make sure your not storing the timezone information in your database.
I'm using Postgres and the column type is **timestamp without time zone**.

This should result in the displayed Date/Time being in UTC. It has worked for me when passing in a Date/Time of **2009-07-13T03:22:53Z** the result is displayed as **2009-07-13T03:22:53+00:00**